# Data array values incompatible types

Tags: java

Not sure why this is wrong I am new to java so please help if you can

> ncompatible types
>   found   : java.lang.Object
>   required: java.lang.String

```
String    sDividendDate1     = data[0][0];
```

**Where**

```
Object[][] data = {
    { "Tom Jones", new Double(5) }, 
    { "Paul Smith", new Double(5) }, 
    { "yyyy/mm/dd", new Double(5) }
}
```

Is `data[0][0]` not the string "Tom Jones" ?

How do I get data that I need from my data array?

Any help will be greatly appreciated - Many thanks Stephen

Comment: Note: `Object[][]` is "an array of arrays which contains Objects". Thus the expression `data[0][0]` has a type of Object which is not assignable to a String (String being a *more specific type* of Object) without a cast or coercion.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that this is a compiler error, because the compiler realizes it cannot assume that all objects are strings. Try casting your returned value like so:

```
String sDividendDate1 = (String)data[0][0];
```

This tells the compiler that you recognize the array *might not* return a String, but that you're willing to risk it because you think you know what that value will actually be at runtime. If the code finds that there isn't really a string there when it goes to do the cast, you'll get a runtime exception.

**Edit**

Andy K has a good point about type safety.  Based on the example you gave it seems like you're trying to represent data that is interrelated. If you can think of names to represent the way the data is related, you can model this more naturally using a class, like so:

```
public class PlayerAverage {
    public PlayerAverage(String name, double average) {
        this.name = name;
        this.average = average
    }
    private String name;
    private double average;

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public double getAverage() {return average;}
}
```

Then you could create an array of these:

```
PlayerAverage[] playerAverages = {
    new PlayerAverage("Tom Jones", 5),
    new PlayerAverage("Paul Smith", 5)
};
```

Because it would be typed, you could easily iterate over this array without the need for any type casting:

```
for(PlayerAverage playerAverage : playerAverages) {
    String name = playerAverage.getName();
    double average = playerAverage.getDouble();
}
```

Note that this approach uses a lot of best-practices like private fields with public getters, which might be overkill for what you're doing. But it's generally a good idea to create classes to indicate how your data is related and what it is supposed to represent.

Comment: Great just seen your answer above - will try this many thanks.

Comment: The above for the string works not sure why double x = (double)data[1][0] is throwing out a complier error even when casting?

Comment: @Stephen: That's because a `double` (lower-case) is a value type (not an Object). That's why you had to use `Double` (upper-case) when you were putting the objects into the array in the first place. Cast it to the upper-case `Double` (which is really just a wrapper object that contains a `double`.

Comment: P.S.: You're breaking a lot of best-practices by using an Object array to hold values with known types. If you share what you're doing, we can give you some advice about a better way to go about it. It would probably be better to create a class with a String and double value, and have a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Although you may cast to fix this, it would be better to improve your code to get type safety.
If possible, use a map.

```
import java.util.*;
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("Tom Jones", 5.0);
map.put("Paul Smith", 5.0);
map.put("yyyy/mm/dd", 5.0);
```

Comment: Thanks Andy K will try this too.

Answer (score 0):

String sDividendDate1 = data[0][0].**toString()**; //return string

Object class is superclass for String class, so sDividendDate1 cannot contain variable of Object class

Comment: While this should work, I would personally prefer a cast over calling toString(). 1: It tells the programmer "I expect this to already be a string". 2: it means that you'll get fail-fast behavior if it isn't a string; you'll know the problem was at this line, rather than having some obscure error arise because "5.0" got passed along. 3: If there is a null string, you'll end up with sDividendDate1 = null, rather than throwing a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you StriplingWarrior but how do I cast it what would the code be please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your description is missing some closing braces. Right now, it's an array of array of array of array...that's never closed. I'd expect to use:

```
Object[][] data = { {"Tom Jones", new Double(5)}, {"Paul Smith", new Double(5)}, {"yyyy/mm/dd", new Double(5) }};
```

Edit: Kirk edited it and fixed the missing braces, but I'm thinking those missing braces were causing the error message you saw at compilation.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  Better as a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it wasn't an answer. The data declaration, as originally posted, was broken and I think that was the answer. His actual accessing of the data was ok.